# How to install zip extension for PHP 7.4 compiled from scratch on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: php

How to install zip extension for PHP 7.4 compiled from scratch on ubuntu 22.04?

i need fix my problem

Notificación
El comando tar no está disponible. Configúrelo correctamente en su "config.inc.php".
Notificación
El comando tar no está disponible. Configúrelo correctamente en su "config.inc.php".

Comment: You don't need to install the zip extension, you need to install "tar" on your host or set the correct path in the "config.inc.php" file.

Comment: The zip extension does not implement such a command.

Comment: I suggest you show the actual php code that raises this error. Otherwise there is little we can offer to help.